# tinymce editor resize feature is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, resize, tinymce

I am using tinymce editor version 3.5.8, and am trying to resize the editor window which is in default not possible i tried adding `autoresize` plugin and also setting the resize property to both in the init function `resize : "both"`

here's my init function

```
tinyMCE.init({

    onchange_callback: "MakeCurrentFormDirty",
    selector: "textarea",
    onkeypress_callback: "Test",
    mode: "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector: "mceEditor",
    theme: "advanced",
    plugins: "preview",
    resize: "both",


setup: function (ed) {
    ed.on('init', function () {
        $(ed.getWin()).bind('resize', function (e) {
            console.log('Editor window resized!');
        })
    });
},
```

please help me resolve. Thanks!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may add below code in init function. I doubt it supports tinyMCE 3.5.8.

Please add below and check. It worked for me.

```
mode: theme_advanced_resizing: true,
```

Comment: You supplied code doesn't make any sense and is incorrect JavaScript